# Grunt Deployment with Git

Tags: git, deployment, gruntjs, web-deployment

I don't know if this is the proper place to ask this but I am struggling with the "best practices" when it comes to grunt and deployment. My team uses bitbucket to host repos and rackspace as the servers.

I use grunt to build my site into static files (compiling ejs/less into static html/css). I have a grunt dev with watch tasks and grunt prod which does all of the optimization/minification etc.

At the moment the deployment process is:

1) grunt prod

2) git commit / git push

3) submit a pull request in bitbucket, merge code into master

4) ssh into server and git pull.

This ensures that whatever I have on the server is a git commit and has been reviewed. One of the issues I have experienced with this is sometimes I forget to run grunt prod before I commit and then end up with an unoptimized site.

I have looked into using a ssh deploy method, basically FTPing the files over after running grunt prod. This would eliminate the step of having to ssh into the server and know commands. I am concerned this method may end up out of sync with git and avoid the step of code reviews/pull requests.

I think I am on the cusp of doing things correctly but I feel like I must be missing something!

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: I'm of the firm belief that distributable files should stay out of version control. Have you thought about flipping things around and committing only *source* files to Git and then using Grunt as the deployment tool to check out, build and deploy your files? That way your whole deployment pipeline is automated and it's impossible to miss a step or commit  the wrong files.

Comment: Thanks @AntP for the quick reply! I have considered it but I haven't been able to wrap my head around how to do it correctly. Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this

> [being able to] eliminate the step of having to ssh into the server and know commands

Bit bucket supports POST commit hooks, more info here:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks

Basically what happens is that when you commit to the bitbucket repo, bitbucket will make a HTTP request to a URL of your choice (with a payload containing info about your commit).
You have a script e.g. PHP or whatever serverside lang you use which fires when the URL is hit and then runs your `git pull` or what ever commands you want.

here is an in depth guide on the process
http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/

> FTPing the files over

This could be pretty difficult and slow, i.e. how would you track which files changed?  how would you deal with the deletion of files on your local project folder and then updating the remote with those removals?

For this I would use **rsync** which is an excellent synchronisation tool.

I know this isn't a full solution, and doesn't solve the problem of forgetting to run `grunt prod` but hopefully it might be of some help to you.